# Can we sync all the MS Teams documents to be inside a sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sync, microsoft-teams

I have received a question from one of our clients, if they can sync all the documents inside multiple MS Teams into a single SharePoint document library? this will ease searching and filtering all the MS documents from one place. so i am not sure if there is a way to have such a sync?

Answer (score 2):

There was a user voice about this and below is the last update from there :

"Yes, just create Teams/Channels as you need and add for each of them the existing SharePoint site as additional cloud provider."

Source :

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/multiple-teams-for-the-same-sharepoint/m-p/235678

However, if it allows for multiple teams with single SharePoint site - the purpose of teams will be messed up, document will come from multiple teams to single library and it will be very difficult to manage and organize.

Let's understand how Microsoft Teams and SharePoint work. When a user create a team from Microsoft Teams a corresponding SharePoint team site will be created automatically and documents from team chanel will be stored in the default document library ie **Shared Document**  -  so as many team you create, a team site will continue to be created - this is one to one mapping.  And also for each team a office 365 group will be created and many other internal things happens.

So the default behavior Microsoft Teams should not change.

So the ideal solution or recommendation would be to make the user experience easier on this to find all team documents from single place, we can think of creating a search web part where we can get all team sites(created through the Microsoft Teams)  documents from single dashboard or place - so need to think at the search level not at team level.

Comment: so you mean to add a search web part which search all the MS Teams ,, so in this case we can have multiple MS teams (hence multiple SharePoint sites) that can be searched from a single place?? did i get your point correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly you got it right.